# MongoDB sort query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation

```
db.data.insert({userAjax: 'sean',date:'26/04/2014',latv:'78.134123', lonv:'43.
342123', distance:'1.23', hours:'0', minutes:'4', seconds:'21', speed: '1.04' })

db.data.insert({userAjax: 'sean',date:'26/04/2014',latv:'78.134123', lonv:'43.
342123', distance:'1.23', hours:'0', minutes:'4', seconds:'21', speed: '1.04' })

db.data.insert({userAjax: 'sean',date:'25/04/2014',latv:'78.134123', lonv:'43.
342123', distance:'0.43', hours:'0', minutes:'2', seconds:'47', speed: '1.33' })

db.data.insert({userAjax: 'sean',date:'25/04/2014',latv:'78.134123', lonv:'43.
342123', distance:'0.43', hours:'0', minutes:'7', seconds:'55', speed: '1.33' })
```

this is a sample structure of my collection. on the website I need to display the dates but only the latest insert for that date,

The data is comming from the mobile phone(geolocation) through ajax and on the client side the latest date that was inserted has to be displayed.

Comment: Firstly please correct your document structure and save date as date object and not string.

Comment: it is a date object in the project, I am using phonegap geolocation timestamp value, this values above are only to show what my collection looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well presumably you are sorting by date for a given user so:

```
db.data.find({ "userAjax": "sean" }).sort({ "date": -1 }).limit(1)
```

Gives you just one result at the latest date for that user.

On the other hand if you are looking for the last result in each day then you can do this with the help of the [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) function:

```
db.data.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "userAjax": "sean" } },
    { "$project": {
        "_id": { 
            "date": {
                "year": { "$year": "$date" },
                "month": { "$month": "$date" },
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }
            }
        },
        "userAjax": "$userAjax",
        "date": "$date",
        "latv": "$latv", 
        "lonv": "$longv", 
        "distance": "$distance", 
        "hours": "$hours",
        "minutes": "$minutes", 
        "seconds": "$seconds", 
        "speed": "$speed" 
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "$first": "$_id" },
        "userAjax": { "$first": "$userAjax" },
        "date": { "$first": "$date" },
        "latv": { "$first": "$latv" }, 
        "lonv": { "$first": "$longv" },
        "distance": { "$first": "$distance" },
        "hours": { "$first": "$hours" },
        "minutes": { "$first": "$minutes" }, 
        "seconds": { "$first": "$seconds" }, 
        "speed": { "$first": "$speed" }
    }}
])
```

Which is a lot more terse, but that is what you want.

Comment: this only gives me the latest result for today, the idea that the data is sent to the server let say today and on the website I want to display latest insert for today's date, then tomorrow data is sent again with tomorrow's date and I want the webiste to display both dates and its latest inserts

Comment: Not really clear in your question. What are you actually looking for the "last" result in each day?

Comment: @user1785982 Then there is a form to do that. A lot more involved but it does do the job

Comment: what form? could u please explain a little bit more? I am using node.js and Jade templating engine if it matters

Comment: @user1785982 Responses like this usually indicate you to re-read the answer given as it has been edited. Welcome to stack overflow.